# How can I set authorization header in my Unity3D game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having some problems where I'm trying to send `Authorization` header to my server in Unity. I've already done this in my Windows Phone project that I'm porting to Unity but when I send the request to my server it returns `500 Internal Server Error`.

Here is my code where I do the call:

```
    string hash = Helper.GetHashString(); 

    byte[] toEncodeAsBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(username + ":" + password);
    string base64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(toEncodeAsBytes); 

    Hashtable headers = new Hashtable();
    headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + base64; 

    StartCoroutine(Server.Authorize(Config.SERVER_URL + "/Auth/" + hash, LoginEventResponse, headers));
```

The Server.Authorize:

```
public static IEnumerator Authorize(string path, DelegateEventFunction myEvent, Hashtable headers)
{
    WWW www = new WWW(SERVER_URL + path, null, headers); 

    yield return www;
```

When the www returns I get the error (500) as mentioned above. The code that I'm porting from, and is working is:

```
            string hash = Helper.GetHashString(); 

            byte[] toEncodeAsBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Model.Username + ":" + Model.Password);
            string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(toEncodeAsBytes); 

            HttpClient loginClient = new HttpClient();
            loginClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", base64); 

            string loginResponse = await loginClient.GetStringAsync(Config.SERVER_URL + "/Auth/" + hash);
```

Very much the same besides the Unitys use of WWW instead of HttpClient. Maybe this is solvable by buying PRO version letting me tap into native libraries, but every webcall works besides this one there I try to send in Authorization header. 
Anyone got a tips?

**EDIT**

I've got this off the logs:

```
Error X-Token: chars_and_numbers,,chars_and_numbers2
Error Exception: Sequence contains no elements in System.Core
```

Google indicates that there is something wring with the encoding? I use the same method, UTF8 all the way...

Comment: You're getting _internal_ error at the server, but you're only showing client-side code here. How does the server code, which throws the error, look?

Comment: Hi golergka, as I mentioned my Windows Phone project runs just fine, and I'm asking if Im doing it wrong or anything in Unity

Comment: It still would help diagnosing the problem. Can you at least include  requests that Unity and the Windows Phone projects are sending to the server?

Comment: @golergka ive added the errors from the log, but I've still got no clue